# Assembly Segments in opcodes

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, addressing-mode, memory-segmentation

I noticed that in Assembly segments are used in opcodes.

Example:

```
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-30],30
```

I think that "PTR SS:" is used to specify that EBP-30 comes from the stack? (SS: stack segment)
Am I right or am I completely wrong? :) And, could you please tell me the difference between the example above and

```
MOV DWORD PTR[EBP-30],30
```

And what about DS (data segment) used in opcodes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-30],30
```

There are two separate modifiers here, `DWORD PTR` and `SS:`.

The first one tells us that we want to store a word at the address pointed to. This is needed when the assembler cannot tell that from the operands of the instruction. Here `30` could just as well be a byte to store.

The `SS:` is a segment prefix, saying that we want to use an address relative to the stack segment. In this case it isn't strictly needed, because that is the default when using the `ESP` or `EBP` registers. So the second version of the instruction is identical to the first one.

Had you used `EBX` instead of `EBP` there would have been a difference!

Comment: Can someone expand on what difference `EBX` would have made as mentioned in Bo's last sentence?

Answer (score 17):

- SS is Stack Segment
- DS is Data Segment
- PTR - pointer. It's an address.

When you do

```
mov ax, some_variable
```

you are really substituting this form "`mov ax, ds:[pointer_to_variable]`"

In case of SS, you are accessing the value not from DS, but from the stack instead :).
Think of segment registers as banks. Data comes from DS, Stack data from SS, Code data from CS, Extra segment is ES.

Comment: Thank you, any link / keyword I can search for to get more info about that?

Comment: I do not know the resources.. I just read everything I could find on google until I understand :)

Comment: @user1365914: Download Intel's or AMD's CPU manuals. They explain all instructions, segments, prefixes, everything. Except, of course, the syntax of the assembler you're using (MASM, TASM, etc). For that you need to consult your assembler's documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll download those two manuals as soon as possible.

Comment: As I remember, Intel send the printed copies of their books for free. I received 5 at a time(3 Instruction manuals, basic architecture and optimisation guide). All the books were 17cm in height in total!