# Assembly language loading SI with BX saying invalid use

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm, addressing-mode

In my masm project there is one line of code as given below

```
LDS SI,[SS:BX]
```

When i try to execute above line of code then MASM gives following error:

```
ERROR: invalid use of 
register
```

Please guide me.

Comment: MASM might want the segment override outside the square brackets?  That syntax assembles fine with NASM, but that's a different assembler with significant syntax differences.

Comment: `SS:[BX]` should work;  [Assembly Segments in opcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820836) shows that's where MASM-style disassembly puts the ss prefix.